# JSON schema draft4 VS JSON schema draft3

Tags: json, jsonschema

What are the features present in the schema draft 4 that are not in the JSON schema draft 3 produced by IETF ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the change logs:

New keywords

- anyOf (match at least one schema in the schema array),
- allOf (match all schemas in the schema array),
- oneOf (match exactly one schema in the schema array),
- not (do not match the schema),
- multipleOf (replaces divisibleBy),
- minProperties and maxProperties (the minimum and maximum number of members in an object instance),
- definitions (standardized container for inlined subschemas).

Removed:

- disallow
- extends
- divisbleBy

Changed in functionality:

### Type

- When the value is an array, schemas are no longer allowed as elements. Also, the array must have at least one element.

**Before**

---

```
{
    "type": [ "string", { "other": "schema" } ]
}
```

**Now**

---

```
{
   "anyOf": [
       { "type": "string" },
       { "other": "schema" }
    ]
}
```

### Required

- Before, it was an attribute of subschemas in properties. It is now a first level keyword playing the same role, and has a string array as an argument.

**Before**

---

```
{
    "properties": {
        "p": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "q": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    }
}
```

**Now**

---

```
{
    "properties": {
        "p": { "type": "string" },
        "q": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "required": [ "p", "q" ]
}
```

### Dependencies

- A single string in a property dependency is no longer allowed, only arrays are allowed

**Before**

---

```
{
    "dependencies": { "a": "b" }
}
```

**Now**

---

```
{
    "dependencies": { "a": [ "b" ] }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm working on a pretty big project where json-schema is super important. It's going to be fun times when/if Json.Net ever decides to move from draft 3 to 4.

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in a deep dive, you can [review a diff between the two drafts on the IETF site](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcdiff?url1=draft-zyp-json-schema-03.txt&url2=draft-zyp-json-schema-04.txt).

However, if you're looking for a simpler summary of changes, Geraint Luff and Francis Galiegue created a [changelog page](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/ChangeLog) on the project's github wiki that lists the changes, additions, and removals.